# Convert For loop into Parallel.For loop

Tags: c#-4.0

```
public void DoSomething(byte[] array, byte[] array2, int start, int counter)
{

    int length = array.Length;
    int index = 0;

         while (count >= needleLen)
         {
             index = Array.IndexOf(array, array2[0], start, count - length + 1);

             int i = 0;
             int p = 0;

             for (i = 0, p = index; i < length; i++, p++)
             {
                  if (array[p] != array2[i])
                  {
                       break;
                  }
             }
```

Answer (score 2):

Given that your for loop appears to be using a loop body dependent on ordering, it's most likely not a candidate for parallelization.

However, you aren't showing the "work" involved here, so it's difficult to tell what it's doing.  Since the loop relies on both i and p, and it appears that they would vary independently, it's unlikely to be rewritten using a simple Parallel.For without reworking or rethinking your algorithm.

In order for a loop body to be a good candidate for parallelization, it typically needs to be order independent, and have no ordering constraints.  The fact that you're basing your loop on two independent variables suggests that these requirements are not valid in this algorithm.